# Spring project suddenly failing to load context - no code changes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, namespaces

I am developing a Spring 3 application that uses Spring Data JPA.

Yesterday, the project was building fine in TeamCity, but today the build is failing locally and on the build server *with no code changes*.

The stack trace mentions namespace handlers.  Here is the namespace section of the config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">
```

Has Spring changed some of the XSD files?

Any suggestions welcomed.

The stack trace is:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [core-jpa-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1bfd9cd5] to prepare test instance [au.com.intellibill.services.event.EventServiceTest@3341b736]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [core-jpa-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:205)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler.init(JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler.java:34)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:130)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Is it `spring-jpa-1.1.xsd` or `spring-jpa-3.1.xsd` in the context.xml

Comment: Confirm "no code changes" by rolling back to everything that was checked in yesterday. If still a problem, check that there have been no changes to TeamCity configuration and/or the server on which it runs, including environment settings, TeamCity version, libraries installed etc.

Comment: Usha - spring jpa is on 1.1 at the moment

Comment: Bohemian - I triggered the build on TeamCity, and verified that the Mercurial revision was identical in both cases.  I did the rollback etc, but same behaviour!  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Springsource released 3.2.0 last night, and they have evidently changed some of the XSDs which breaks my build.

The solution is to upgrade to 3.2.0 (I was on 3.1.3), and magically everything works again...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a version mismatch issue between JPA and Spring and Spring Data Commons Core. I was getting a similar error

```
 Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] 
 for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; 
 nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
```

I changed and introduced the entries were as follows. Note the versions agains each schema.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

The Spring and JPA versions were 3.1.3.RELEASE. I downgraded the Spring version to 3.1.2.RELEASE and the problem was resolved. But the same solution may or may not work depending on other dependencies. The other dependent versions are as below

```
  <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring-data-jpa.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
  <spring-data-commons-core.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring-data-commons-core.version>
```