# Spring - Error using "JDBCTemplate": The method "X" refers to the missing type DataAccessException

Tags: spring, jdbc

I´m developing in STS and when I´m going to use JDBC Template I´ve got several errors :S...

I´ve got my DAOImplementation and I want to redefine the JDBCTemplate, but all the methods I´m redefining returns errors like:

*The type org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The method query(String, RowMapper) from the type JdbcTemplate refers to the missing type DataAccessException*

Concretly, the methods are:

- Update.
- QueryForString.
- Query.

I have imported all dependencies for Maven, I don´t know what is happening...

I hope you could help me, thanks for all :).

Juandi.

Comment: It may help if you post what you are doing (code).  Sounds like you are trying to override certain JDBCTemplate methods... why?

Comment: Hello! I think I´ve fixed the problem. I have imported an external JAR that contains the DataAccesException.class and seems that works, but when I run the app got this error:

ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class.

Any idea :/?...

Comment: No. It would help us help you if you can post the full stack trace in your post above (edit your original post, format it. See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871045/spring-project-suddenly-failing-to-load-context-no-code-changes)) and also include relevant parts of your config.

Answer (score 8):

In spring 3 the whole jar structure has been re-organized. There is no all-in-one spring.jar as before. You have to pick what you need.
DataAccessException is in org.springframework.transaction-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar

include this jar in class path.

Answer (score 4):

i had same problem add the `spring-tx-XXX.jar` to you project xxx means version

Answer (score 2):

In spring framework 4.1, "org.springframework.transaction.xxx.jar" is to be imported instead of spring-tx-xxx.jar

Answer (score 0):

Adding
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar

solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Same on my case, I used Spring-mvc 4.3.0 and have a spring-tx.4.3.0 and DataAccessException in there.

But I haved an error like your case.

Solution : I just deleted Spring-tx Folder dependency in maven repo (.m2/repository/) and update dependency again. It was solved to me.